# How To Scrape Table Into Dataframe From The Webpage

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape table into dataframe with one page.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.viewbase.com/funding")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

table1 = soup.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: df = pd.read_html(str(soup.find('table'))) Try something like this.

Comment: thx. have tried but can only scape table title instead of data.

Comment: It seems bs4 can't grab the values use selenium instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want the headers as well

```
driver.get("https://www.viewbase.com/funding")
tbl = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('table')
headers = tbl.find_elements_by_xpath('//thead/tr[2]/th')
headers = [item.text.strip() for item in headers]
trs = tbl.find_elements_by_xpath('tbody/tr')
lst=[]

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    tds = [item.text.strip() for item in tds]
    lst.append([item for item in tds if item])

#print(lst)
print(headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

Outputs so far

```
['', 'Binance', 'FTX', 'Okex', 'Bybit', 'Binance', 'Huobi', 'Okex', 'Bitmex', 'Bybit', '']
        0         1         2         3  ...         6         7        8        9
0     BTC   0.0100%   0.0020%  -0.0062%  ...   0.0034%  -0.0047%  0.0100%  0.0100%
1     ETH   0.0100%   0.0010%  -0.0034%  ...   0.0100%   0.0111%  0.0193%  0.0100%
2     XRP   0.0100%   0.0013%   0.0003%  ...  -0.0096%  -0.0089%  0.0100%  0.0100%
3     EOS   0.0100%   0.0017%  -0.0098%  ...   0.0100%   0.0186%        -  0.0100%
4     BCH   0.0100%   0.0006%   0.0227%  ...   0.0100%   0.0135%  0.0110%        -
5     LTC   0.0100%  -0.0012%   0.0180%  ...   0.0100%   0.0006%  0.0100%        -
6    LINK   0.0031%  -0.0004%  -0.0272%  ...  -0.0321%  -0.0221%        -        -
7     BSV         -  -0.0020%  -0.0280%  ...   0.0105%  -0.0468%        -        -
8     BNB  -0.1475%  -0.0046%         -  ...         -         -        -        -
```

[59 rows x 10 columns]

Import

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the headers. But when I run the code, I met the errors of "NameError: name 'driver' is not defined" . Even if I run "driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)", it is not working.

Comment: You have to pip install selenium and get a chromedriver

Comment: You could use driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options), from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager, and pip install webdriver-manager.

Comment: Instead of getting a chromedriver.

Answer (score 1):

The table is populated via a JS script, so BS4 won't see it. However, you could use `selenium` in `headless` mode and grab what you need.

Here's how to do this:

```
import time

import pandas as pd

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://www.viewbase.com/funding")
time.sleep(5)
headers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="tablesorter-headerRow"][2]/th/div')
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="inverse_swap"]')

columns = [i.text for i in headers]
data = [r.split() for r in table.text.split('\n')]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Appreciate for your answer. But get some errors when running your code. i am working on it:)

Comment: You need to install `selenium` with `pip install -U selenium` and get the webdriver from here - http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: So surprised about how talented people are on the stack overflow. I have upvoted your answer but my reputation is too low to show it. Thanks very much.